# Java EE Qualifier annotation not picked up

Tags: dependency-injection, java-ee-7

I am following a simple Java EE 6 annotations video on youtube. I have created a [repo](https://github.com/8indaas/example-cdi-producer-methods-1) on github. There is a servlet to start with that creates a greeting string using annotation.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/HelloServlet"})
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject @Formal
    String greetingMessage;
...
}
```

The formal qualifier is defined as follows:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface Formal {}
```

And the producer is:

```
public class ProduceFormalGreeting {

    @Produces
    @Formal
    public String GetFormalGreeting(){
        return "Good morning !";
    }
}
```

At compile time I get the following message from NetBeans:

```
Unsatisfied Dependency: No bean matches the inject point
```

At runtime, the string is `null` in the servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `beans.xml` file to WEB-INF. Now You have `bean.xml` file.

In `ProduceFormalGreeting` u have to use `javax.enterprise.inject.Produces` (not `javax.ws.rs.Produces`)

Comment: I changed to beans.xml. Same result. Unsatisfied dependencies for type [String] with qualifiers [\@Formal] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] \@Inject \@Formal mypackage.HelloServlet.greetingMessage]

Comment: You have one more error. In `ProduceFormalGreeting` u have to use `javax.enterprise.inject.Produces` (not `javax.ws.rs.Produces`)

Comment: You're welcome. BTW. I have updated my answer, now mentioned problems are collected together.